# Max Aggregate function in Teradata-

Tags: teradata

If I have below data :

```
EMP_ID      EMP_DEPT    JOIN_DATE    END_DATE
1           HR          2/12/2015    8/23/2015
1           HR          4/5/2015     5/20/2015
```

and have query as:

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_dept, max(join_date), max(end_date)
FROM emp
GROUP BY 1,2
```

What will be the output ??

Comment: What do you mean by GROUP BY 1,2

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: Some RDBMSs allow for column ordinals to be used in a `group by` clause. So, in this case, `group by 1,2` is the same as `group by emp_id, emp_dept`.

Comment: As for the question...why not just build the table, try out the query yourself, and see what happens?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it? And why do you think this is a Teradata-specifc question?

Answer (score -2):

Without group by 1,2 only with group by EMP_ID the O/P would be:- So the query would be:-

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_dept, MAX(join_date), MAX(end_date) 
FROM emp 
GROUP BY emp_id, emp_dept;

EMP_ID      EMP_DEPT    JOIN_DATE    END_DATE
1           HR          4/5/2015     8/23/2015
```

Comment: Ummm...I do believe that query will result in a syntax error, since you're not grouping by `emp_dept` (something to the effect of `The column 'emp_dept' must appear in a GROUP BY clause or aggregate`).

Comment: I accept my fault. I was in so hurry to tell him the logic rather than the syntax........